# kafka connect sink to mongo only last result with delay

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

i have aggregation query `pageView` group by `country`, results push to out topic.

And sink to **mongodb** by kafka connector

```
{
    "connector.class": "MongoDbAtlasSink",
    "name": "confluent-mongodb-sink",
    "input.data.format" : "JSON",
    "connection.host": "ip",
    "topics": "viewPageCountByUsers",
    "max.num.retries": "3",
    "retries.defer.timeout": "5000",
    "max.batch.size": "0",
    "database": "test",
    "collection": "ViewPagesCountByUsers",
    "tasks.max": "1"
}
```

The problem is that this data is very frequent and very load mongodb. How i can set kafkaconnection that send only last value by key as batch, example with 5 sec delay ?
Example: It's pointless to update the database 5 times

```
{countryID:7, viewCount: 111}
{countryID:7, viewCount: 112}
{countryID:7, viewCount: 113}
{countryID:7, viewCount: 114}
{countryID:7, viewCount: 115}
```

If there was an opportunity send only last result by key with 5 sec delay i can update 1 time.

```
// collect batch 5 sec and flush: 
{countryID:7, viewCount: 115}
{countryID:8, viewCount: 573}
```

How do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sink connectors just take whatever is in the topic, generally  without batching.

You'd need to use a stream-processor such as Kafka Streams / KSQLdb to run a windowed-aggregation, then output to a new topic, which you'd read from the sink connector.

Comment: "max.batch.size": "0",  and then what are these parameters ? its from official  sink mongo connector manual

Comment: Like I said - "generally". Most sink connectors don't. Regarding the Mongo one, that setting doesn't "dedupe data by keys", it just fills up an internal queue to the set size, then writes all those records to the database, saving only on total needed network requests